# Using ValueInjecter, is there a way to only inject a given property one time

Tags: valueinjecter

Given 3 classes,

A, and B which each have an ID property, and then various other properties

and C, which has an ID, and the combined properties of A and B,

I want to

```
C.InjectFrom(A);
C.InjectFrom(B);
```

such that the ID from A is preserved and not overwritten by B.

Obviously in this simple case, I could just reverse the order of the two calls, but in my real world example, it is slightly more complicated where I cannot just solve the problem with ordering.

Esentially I want the second injection to ignore anything that the first injection has already handled, and this may be continued down a chain of several injections. Some of these injections may be from the same objects too

```
C.InjectFrom(A);
C.InjectFrom<SomeInjector>(A);
C.InjectFrom<SomeInjector2>(A);
C.InjectFrom<SomeInjector3>(A);
```

etc.

Comment: in a few words the solution will be to create a custom injection that will take an object in the constructor, in this object you would store  the names of the properties that have been handled already, and you pass this object to each .InjectFrom(new MyInj(obj), An), so in the MyInj you will ignore the props that are in the obj and store the ones that you handle

Comment: This works for the vanilla injector logic, but does not allow for use of any other types of injector without rewriting them to add this functionality :(

Comment: usually you need about 3 injections or something, you could create this way your own OnceConventionInjection and after inherit from it instead of the ConventionInjection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Omu.ValueInjecter;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var a = new { Id = 1, P1 = "p1" };
            var b = new { Id = 2, P2 = "p2" };

            var c = new C();

            var propList = new List<string>();
            c.InjectFrom(new HandlePropOnce(propList), a);
            c.InjectFrom(new HandlePropOnce(propList), b);

            Console.WriteLine("Id = {0} P1 = {1} P2 = {2}", c.Id, c.P1, c.P2);
        }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string P1 { get; set; }

        public string P2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class HandlePropOnce : ConventionInjection
    {
        private readonly IList<string> handledProps;

        public HandlePropOnce(IList<string> handledProps)
        {
            this.handledProps = handledProps;
        }

        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            if (handledProps.Contains(c.SourceProp.Name)) return false;

            var isMatch = c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name && c.SourceProp.Type == c.TargetProp.Type;

            if (isMatch) handledProps.Add(c.SourceProp.Name);
            return isMatch;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I no longer am stuck on this issue (hopefully obviously) what would completely solve the issue, and perhaps be a nice feature for you, would be to allow nested injectors.  Doing something like  InjectFrom<HandlePropOnce<ArbitraryInjector>> would be great (and could be valuable many other places too) - but this would require to move the looping logic separate from the mapping/conversion logic. That seems smart to me anyway, but it may be too far down the road now.